# Get compiled template for controller in unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controller, jasmine

I have the following controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('userList'
 , ['$scope','appRules',function ($scope,appRules) {
  $scope.isUserInRole=function(user,role){
    console.log("exucuting userIsInRole:",user,role);//never happens
    return  appRules.userIsInRole(user,role);
  }
  window.sscope=$scope;
  console.log($scope.menu);
}]);
```

This is used for the following route:

```
angular.module('app', [,'ui.bootstrap','ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider'
,function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  $routeProvider
          .when('/admin/users',{
            templateUrl:'app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html',
            controller:'userList'
          });
}]);
```

The template would have something that will check if user can see this page or not (even if someone hacks javascript it doesn't matter because when data is fetched or submitted the server checks as well).

```
<div data-ng-if="!isUserInRole(login.user,'Administrator')" class="red">
  Please log in or log in as another user.
</div>
<div data-ng-if="isUserInRole(login.user,'Administrator')" class="green">
  Page to edit users.
</div>
```

Now I would like to create a controller in my test and see when it renders if it renders correctly:

```
  var controller,scope,element;

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller
   ,$rootScope,$compile,appRules) {
    scope=$rootScope;
    scope.login={};
    scope.isUserInRole=appRules.userIsInRole;
    controller = $controller('userList',{
      $scope:scope
    });
    //here I have the controller but how to get the html it generates
    //  when rendering the template?
    element = $compile("<div ng-controller='userList'>"
      +"<div data-ng-view=''></div></div>")(scope);
    //here element isn't rendered at all, works on directives but how
    //  to do this with controllers?
    console.log("element is:",element);
  }));
```

I would like to write a test like

```
  it('Check page won\'t show if user is not set or is not Administrator.'
  , function() {
    expect($(element).text().trim()
      .indexOf("Please log in or log in as another user."))
      .toBe(0,'Show login message when login.user is not set.');
  });
```

Not sure how to get element though.

**[update]**

I'm actually trying to test a template, because this is used by a controller I was thinking testing it with a controller but as Jon suggested it can just be loaded as template.

How to make it compile and manipulate scope and compile again I don't know. The following:

```
var el = angular.element(
  $templateCache
  .get('app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html'));
$rootScope = _$rootScope_;
$rootScope.menu={login:{}};
el.scope($rootScope);
$rootScope.$apply();
console.log(el.text());
```

This gives me the output of both `Please log in or log in as another user.` and `Page to edit users.` Looks like element is just the raw element not compiled one.

Trying something like this doesn't do much either:

```
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_
   , _$rootScope_,appSettings,$templateCache){
    console.log("before each");
    var el = angular.element($templateCache
      .get('app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html'));
    var compile=_$compile_;
    var $rootScope=_$rootScope_;
    $rootScope.login:{};
    $rootScope.isUserInRole=appSettings.userIsInRole;
    //I would think that compile would invoke the ng-if and appSettings.userIsInRole
    //  but no console log in that function is shown.
    var element = compile($templateCache
      .get('app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html'))($rootScope);
    console.log("element is:",element.html());//=undefined    
  }));
```

Comment: A controllers scope is isolated so unless your userList controller is applied to an html element that encapsulates all other this will not work as a scalable solution as it requires lots of nested scopes which increase memory.  I've written a blog post about user security in angular which is a better, more scalable approach - http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Comment: @JonSamwell Thank you for your reply. In general; if I want to check if a loading image is shown when the route/controller is used because somewhere else a directive needs to fetch some data and then want to see if this is gone when fetching data is fetched/resolved how would I go about testing that? I can mock http service promises and see how a directive renders but this is a controller that's used on certain routes. Have not been able to find any working code to test this.

Comment: This sounds a bit more like an intergration test issue.  Unit test should test isolation so you should test that the thing that loads the  image is triggered on http calls via a route interceptor then you should have separates tests to test the thing that actually does the dom manipulation to put the image on the screen - maybe ask a separate question for that one.

Comment: @JonSamwell I would like to test the template to display one thing when scope.login.loading is true, another when scope.login.loading is false and scope.login.user is truethy and yet another thing when scope.login.user is true. Since the template is used by a controller I thought I add the test in the controller but could as well just leave the controller out of it if there is a way to compile the template with different scopes. The part that changes the scope is covered in another unit test but I want to make sure the template behaves correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Add your templates to the cache using ng-templates or ng-html2js so they are available when Karma runs. Then do this:

var scope = null;

```
beforeEach(inject(function($templateCache,_$compile_,_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {

    //get the template from the cache
    template = $templateCache.get('src/main/app/components/someController/widget-search.tpl.html');

    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $controller = _$controller_;

    scope = $rootScope.new();
    //compile it
    element = $compile(template)(scope);
}));

 //then shove your compiled element into your controller instance



it( 'should be instantiated since it does not do much yet', function(){

            ctrl = $controller('SomeController',
                {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $element: element
                });

             scope.$digest();

            // my controller should set a variable called hasInstance to true when it initializes. Here i'm testing that it does.
            expect( ctrl.hasInstance).toBeTruthy();

        });
```

For more info, see http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/06/introduction-to-unit-test-directives/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, are you sure this is supposed to work? All I get is failed test: `Expected undefined to be truthy.` At the moment I'm compiling the template using a dummy directive with transclude true.

Comment: of course, you'd have to have a property called hasInstance- that's my variable i'm testing. My controller makes a hasInstance = true on init. Here, i make sure it does what I want it to.

Comment: oh, totally forgot, you need to $scope.$digest() or nothing's going to happen with your compiled element. In karma, it doesn't do these for you, like $scope.$apply() and $timeout.flush()

Comment: $rootScope.new is not a function, it is meant to be $rootScope.$new.

Comment: Having controller created this way - is it possible to interact with it by playing with provided element (for example. `.triggerHandler('click')`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Karma you could use the [ng-html2js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) karma pre processor which basically runs through your templates and turns them into module which you can include in your test which populate the $templateCache so your template is available.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. No template is loaded. They are all compiled as js file. In the template file is something like: `$templateCache.put('app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html',...`

Comment: Then you could just get it from the template cache? $templateCache.get('app/js/partials/admin/users/list.html') and you will have the html string - you could then just do angular.element(htmlStr) and you would have a new element.

Comment: I've updated my answer. How exactly am I to use this angular.element with scope and compile it?