# Angular 1.x Jasmine testing directive that uses variable from `controller As` syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a directive using Jasmine + Karma and for other ones I have tested they have worked no problem. However this template has `ng-if="vm.validUser"`. The template I grab using `$templateCache.get()` shows that the template is in fact grabbed. The problem is using `$compile` the `element.html()` will come up undefined in the `expect` test. I am trying to set the `scope.vm.validUser = true` or `scope.controller.validUser = true` as `vm` is just a reference but both are not working.

**Template** (Shortend to show relative information):

```
<section ng-cloak ng-if="vm.validUser">
  <!-- more HTML -->
</section>
```

Controller:

```
// More JS
var vm = this;
vm.validUser = false;
// More JS
```

**Jasmine Test Suite:**

```
controller = _$controller_('userController as vm',
{
  $scope: scope,
  $element: element,
  UserFactory:  _UserFactory_
});

template = $templateCache.get('pathToTemplate'); // Create instance of template

scope.vm={
  validUser : true
};

element = _$compile_(template)(scope);
scope.$digest(); // will run watchers and resolve angular expressions in template

describe('userPage.tpl.html tests', function() {

  it('should have template defined', function() {

    console.log("TEST,", template);
    console.log("TEST 2", scope.vm);
    console.log("TEST 3", element);

    expect(element.html()).toBeDefined()
});
```

**Results:**

As you can see I have three console logs in my test. The first one for `template` shows the entire html as expected. The second shows that `validUser` does equal `true`. `Element` shows the result of `LOG: 'Test 3', {0: <!-- ngIf: vm.validUser-->, length: 1}`.

The actual `expect` test fails and states "Expected undefined to be defined"

To my understanding, and from what I have read, this should be working.

Links I found Helpful:

- http://blog.cdh.com/unit-testing-angularjs-directives-with-external-templates
- http://derpturkey.com/unit-testing-directives-in-angular/
- http://busypeoples.github.io/post/testing-angularjs-directives/
- https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/
- https://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html#testing-directives
- http://daginge.com/technology/2014/03/03/testing-angular-directive-controllers-with-jasmine-and-karma/
- [Get compiled template for controller in unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837571/get-compiled-template-for-controller-in-unit-test)
- http://daginge.com/technology/2013/12/14/testing-angular-templates-with-jasmine-and-karma/
- http://blog.cdh.com/unit-testing-angularjs-directives-with-external-templates